# Check if record exists where child has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, exists

I'm building an interface where people can submit tags for the content of various websites so each `Submission` has a parameter `domain` and `has_one :tag`.

The trick is that I would like to check to see if that tag has previously been submitted for that domain before saving.

Something like:

```
Submission.where(domain: submission_params[:domain], tag.tag_text: submission_params[:tag][:tag_text]).exists?
```

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks for checking in.  I had a bunch of other stuff come up so I haven't been able to give it a shot yet.  I should be able to in the next couple hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to query the associated table, you should JOIN it. In your case [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) is what you're looking for (*INNER JOIN*):

```
Submission.joins(:tag)
          .where(
            submissions: { domain: submission_params[:domain] },
            tags:        { tag_text: submission_params[:tag_attributes][:tag_text] }
          ).exists?
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.